# how to get alternative paths between two location in android like google maps provides

Tags: android, path, maps

I am working on a google maps android app. I have to show more then one route between two locations. I have searched a lot but no success. Please give me the direction how can i achieve this.

Please don't mark it as duplicate. I have checked all questions here. No one tells about alternative paths

Thanks.[Please see the attachment this is how i want to show in my app too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pu8Y.png)

Comment: You are using Google directions API?

Comment: And what about [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18975709/4546677)?

Comment: yes i am using google direction api

Comment: @LSA i am looking for android

Comment: google  direction api will return all possible paths in result you need to parse that json result and display in the way u need them

Comment: you are right sir but it returns json of only one path.